# Unable to end code process in 3.5.0

Tags: python-3.x

So while testing my new program for school I used a while loop. But when I try to use the SystemExit command; it keeps asking if I want to start the program in a loop. Is there some way that I can still use the while loop, and not have the end process repeat itself?
here is the code:

```
def main():
    print("This program will convert KG's to LBS and vice versa.")
    name = input("Please print your name: ")
    conversion_input = input("Do you want to convert into KG's or LBS's?")
    if conversion_input == 'KG':
        pounds = int(input("What weight of lbs do you want to convert? "))
        print(pounds, " converted to lbs is: ", pounds * 0.45, "lbs")
    if conversion_input == 'LBS':
        kilo = int(input("What weight in kg's do you want to convert? "))
        print(kilo, " converted to kg is: ", kilo * 2.2, "kgs.")
 main()
 while True:
     n = input('Do you want to try again?')
     if n == 'yes':
        main()
     if n == 'no':
        SystemExit
while False:
     SystemExit
```

Comment: `SystemExit` is not a "command". Who taught you that?

Answer (score 0):

As nneonneo mentioned in a comment, `SystemExit` is not  a "command". It is the type of the exception raised when `sys.exit()` is called, which is what you should be doing here, *e.g.*

```
if n == 'no':
    sys.exit()
```

(You will need to `import sys` at the start of the file to use this, if you haven't already.)

I'm also not sure what you're trying to do with your `while False:` loop at the end. Such a loop will never run.